# Offset of type string on string

Tags: php, variables

i have problem with this. Log page retrun this:

> TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string on file somethin.php:636

This is line 636:

```
$cust = str_replace('[CUSTOMER_NO]',$client_id['response']['client_id'],$temp['response']['customer_no_template']);
```

I use php 8.1

Where is problem thank you.

I tried add `(int)` before variable string, same problem

Comment: The problem is that one of those variables you're trying to treat as an array is actually a string. We don't know which one - there are three possibilities in that one line of code. You'll need to do some debugging.

Comment: `I tried add (int) before variable string`...how would that be relevant?? It's nothing to do with ints.

Comment: Please add the output of `var_dump($client_id, $temp);`

Comment: @Barmar - string(1) "8" NULL

Comment: Ok. So neither of those variables contain arrays. Did you _expect_ them to contain arrays? If so, why? Obviously we don't know how those variables are being populated, earlier in your code, or what you want to achieve with this code, or what the logic is actually supposed to be.

Comment: So `$client_id` isn't an array, what do you expect `$client_id['response']` to be?

Comment: I suspect you already did something like `$client_id = $response['client_id']`. You don't need to index it again.

Comment: @Barmar - Thank you! $client_id['response'] change only on $client_id and everything working tahnks!